# How to filter data in Django admin without returning a queryset?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I need to filter data using python and then return the result (a list of filtered objects) to the admin page like this.

```
class MyFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

  def queryset(self, request, queryset):
      if self.value() == 'delayed_orders':
          filtered_objects = filter(queryset)
          return filtered_objects
```

Is this possible using the admin.SimpleListFilter or we always need to return a queryset ?

Answer (score 1):

After a brief look at `django/contrib/admin/views/main.py` (e.g. `ChangeList.get_queryset`), it becomes clear that it expects something that behaves like a queryset.

If it is worth the hassle, you might try writing a class that wraps/extends the list and would expose the same methods that a `QuerySet` does, or look for an existing implementation.